# AspNetCore MVC Claims - IsInRoleAsync verus Claims

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-core

In my aspnet core MVC app if I retrieve a user using an injected `UserManager` then the following returns `true`:

```
await _userManager.IsInRoleAsync( user, "Administrator" );
```

However, whenever I check `User` (`ClaimsPrincipal`) in a view like so, the claim is missing (returns `false`):

```
User.IsInRole( "Administrator" );
```

This seems inconsistent to me.

Do I have to manually set Role claims myself somewhere? I imagined that would come for free and that a custom `UserClaimsPrincipalFactory` would be for app-specific Claims as opposed to Roles (which come out-of-the-box with MVC).

What am I missing?

Answer (score 0):

It's a known issue in the version of 2.1 and has been fixed in 2.2 preview-1 .

In asp.net core 2.1, `AddDefaultIdentity` is used and the injection becomes to

```
services.AddDefaultIdentity<IdentityUser>()
            .AddRoles<IdentityRole>()
```

,will not make `Roles` enabled by default and it always return false for `User.IsInRole`.

To walk around it , instead of using the new `AddDefaultIdentity<TUser>()` to configure Identity , simply use the old-style api :

```
 services.AddIdentity<IdentityUser, IdentityRole>()
    .AddRoleManager<RoleManager<IdentityRole>>()
    .AddDefaultUI()
    .AddDefaultTokenProviders()
    .AddEntityFrameworkStores<ApplicationDbContext>();
```

Another way is that you could replace the UserClaimsPrincipal factory with the one that's role aware.Add below code in ConfigureService and refer to [UserRoles in DefaultIdentity](https://github.com/aspnet/Identity/issues/1813)

```
services.AddScoped<IUserClaimsPrincipalFactory<IdentityUser>, UserClaimsPrincipalFactory<IdentityUser, IdentityRole>>();
```